# How to type a paragraph in Photoshop. Should be simple, but apparently isn't

Tags: text, typesetting, paragraph

I need help creating a bloc of text in Photoshop. I've succeeded in creating a text box and resizing it without stretching the text. However, I cannot get the text to wrap inside the box. Likewise, when I hit "enter" to move down a line, it doesn't move down; it just types over the line I just entered. This is insanity! Typing a paragraph in a text box should be the most basic of functions! What the heck is going on?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the text and your character and paragraph panels? You don't have your leading set to "0" do you? That's the only reason I could think for the text typing over itself after a new line

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That may be it. I'll have to check tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if I understand the question correctly. But PhotoShop handles creating text in two different ways. You can have a paragraph text (which allows for auto-line breaks) and point text (which is single line.)

Here is a quick video I did of how text is added/created/manipulated.

https://cloudup.com/crbSf3rdeqI

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I double-checked that it was paragraph rather than point.